# retrieve attribute and value of string which is in the format of tages with attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string which contains xml tags with some attributes,

like

```
var myXML='<FragmentDefinition id="frg" group="test">
           <FragmentDefinition id="frg123" group="test123">';
```

I want to write a regular expression which gives me all the id attribute and the values

Output should be

```
id="frg" id="frd123"
```

I am very poor in REgx. I googled it for hours but i didn't find anything. for some reason i need only regular expression, not any xml readers to do my stuff

Comment: Something like `^.*(id="\w+").*\n.*(id="\w+").*$`? Tried [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/oW5cS2/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next source:

```
var result = myXML.match(/id="\w*?"/g);
```

Variable result will be contain array ['id="frg"', 'id="frg123"']

If you want receive string 'id="frg" id="frd123"', you can use next source:

```
var result = myXML.match(/id="\w*?"/g).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this regex:

```
/(id="[a-zA-Z0-9]*")/g
```

So ultimately, you can do:

```
var myXML= '<FragmentDefinition id="frg" group="test"><FragmentDefinition id="frg123" group="test123">';
var res = myXML.match(/(id="[a-zA-Z0-9]*")/g);
```